Ubuntu installation (dualboot mode)
I've been dealing with an operating system installation since yesterday. Ubuntu! And I can't set up the dual boot mode. What have I tried that doesn't work? I have an optibay SSD connected to my laptop. I installed ubuntu on it, but the system automatically loads windows on boot. No option to select the system.in the BIOS settings under manager. Operating systems. Ubuntu is detected, but to change via f-6 and f-5. 0 reactions.Also in the parameters ms config in the boot section does not show the operating system Ubuntu. I ask who has time and ability to help me I will be grateful (I know that it is easy to customize wsl2 ) but where I started training require full-fledged presence of Ubuntu

What version of Ubuntu are you using? To be clear this is a WSL" environment? If it is that is not dual boot. That is running Ubuntu on top of Windows via WSL2.

I installed Ubuntu 24.4 lts no, it's not wsl to me, I put Ubuntu on an SSD drive, I didn't want to create a separate partition on the main disk, but now I have a problem when starting my laptop, the system loads Windows without the possibility of choosing, I have to manually boot Ubuntu through system restore. at the moment I'm at a dead end and I do not know what to do in YouTube there are no clear instructions

Since you made sure the Ubuntu install could not see that Windows was installed it did not create the Grub menu and give the choice. What it is doing is 100 percent correct for the way you installed it.

The name and model of your computer?

This question is similar to: Can't boot into Ubuntu in Windows 10 / Ubuntu dual boot. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
